# SQL SELECT Dynamic column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

is there any way in MS SQL to create dynamic select query like this ? :

```
    DECLARE @cnt INT = 1
    DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(25)
    DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @part NVARCHAR(25) = 'W11282173'

            WHILE @cnt <= 10
                BEGIN
                       Set @query = N'SELECT Check'+str(@cnt)+ N' from udtSmartPlastic where Partnumber ='+@part
                       exec sp_executesql @query;
                       SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
                END
```

I have table like this :

[image]

The idea is to run a while loop and get the specific values from table (all the 10) one by one and set them as a value of some component.

If there is another, easier, more sophisticated way to do it pls tell me.

Expanede code :

```
 DECLARE @cnt INT = 1
 DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(25)
 DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @part NVARCHAR(25) = 'W11282173'
                        WHILE @cnt <= 10
                            BEGIN
                              set @query = N'SELECT Check'+str(@cnt)+ N' from udtSmartPlastic where Partnumber ='+@part
                              exec sp_executesql @query;
                              --SELECT Check+str(1) from udtSmartPlastic where PartNumber = 'W11282173'
                              INSERT INTO @TblReturn VALUES ('txtCheck'+str(@cnt), 'Property', '<property Value='+@value+'/>')
                              SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
                            END
```

I have to get the value from Columns and assign a value of labels Check1..2..3 (basically rename them)

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand your goal here. The dynamic SQL you have would generate 10 `SELECT` statements; each returning a single column. Is that *really* what you are after? If so, yes, this can be rewritten easily without using a `WHILE`.

Comment: Why not fix your data model? - repeating columns is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Yes, exactly need that, there is an code after select that will assign that value to some 'labels' in another program.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Give me a tip to fix my data model pls then.

Comment: `If there is another, easier, more sophisticated way to do it pls tell me.` You are looking for a `more sophisticated way` ?

Comment: @Squirrel Not necessary, but if there is another easier way to do it than I want to know that.

Comment: just need change the table design to 2 columns `PartNumber` & `Check`, your problem will be resolved

Comment: I cant, imagine a program that you have match the users input by the table Check columns values order by check column names

Comment: So, wait, you're trying to make markup language with your output? So, what is your expected output here? (not a picture of a html page, the value).

Comment: Expected output is that I get the values from Check columns one by one based on PartNumber and after SN is filled by user the query runs and renames the Check labels to values given by query, then I have to check If user is entering the same exact value as in table related to PartNumber.

Comment: Stop describing your output; **show us** the expected output in your post.

Comment: The output your query gives me is correct, however it is all in one, I mean I can not use the returned values one by one.

Comment: So you want it in one dataset? Then use the second query. Again: **show us** the expected output in your post.

Comment: I can not show you, I think I have to get the result in loop, because after every returned value I have to do other things with that value.

Comment: Like what? You still aren't explaining your goals. We can't help you if we don't know what you're trying to acheive, however, a `WHILE` loop is very unlikely to be the answer here. At this stage, however, I'm out. I can't keep asking you to explain the logic and be ignored every time. Good luck anyway.

Comment: Hm, I do not know what is not clear about my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This replicates the SQL you have, however, I don't really understand *why* you want to do this:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @Part nvarchar(25) = 'W11282173'

WITH Tally AS (
    SELECT I
    FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) V(I))
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(10) + N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(N'CHECK' + CONVERT(nvarchar(2),T.I)) + N' FROM udtSmartPlastic WHERE Partnumber = @dPart;'
                     FROM Tally T
                     FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,1,N'');

PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@dPart nvarchar(25)',@dPart = @Part;
```

Note that I have changed your query from one open to injection, to a parametrised query. INjection is far from your friend, and you should be making every effort to make it impossible for someone to do.

Edit: As for normalising your data; you could easily achieve this with the following:

```
SELECT SP.PartNumber,
   CHOOSE(T.I,Check1,Check2,Check3,Check4,Check5,Check6,Check7,Check8,Check9,Check10) AS CheckValue
--INTO udtSmartPlasticn
FROM udtSmartPlastic SP
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) T(I);
```

Comment: Actually I do not understand that query at all, so it works but I have to assign the returned value to for example variable one by one, this will return me all in one.

Comment: Assigned what returned value to what? There's no assignment in your example query., @LYR . You need to expand on what your real goal is here. As the comments have shown, it completely unclear. As for understanding, what part is it you don't understand?

Comment: I have updated the code, but this is somebodys own developement not a standart code, If I get value from Check1  I have to assign that value to @value at expanded code.

Comment: I just do not know what is WITH, STUFF, XML PATH I think I am not as clever in SQL as you.

Comment: @LYR [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [STUFF (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) & [FOR XML (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). All 3 of these are actually very common features used in SQL Server; so I suggest familiarising yourself; either by the documentation or my online guides.

Comment: And *"expanded code"* @LYR? Why aren't you sharing the full code for us? Don't drip feed the volunteers trying to help you here, provide the full picture from the get go.

Comment: I can but this is the only part that is needed. The rest is not related to this.